# jQuery-1.9.1.js crashes on IE 7 - javascript runtime error, member not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-7, jquery-1.9

I have a asp.net mvc4 web app. From dev tools, when I switch to IE 7, jquery-1.9.1.js crashes when I go to Login page (the default that comes with internet application template in mvc 4).

jquery-1.9.1.js crashes on line 2582, a piece of the code:

```
// IE6/7 do not support getting/setting some attributes with get/setAttribute
if ( !getSetAttribute ) {

    // Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
    // This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
    nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
        get: function( elem, name ) {
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            return ret && ( name === "id" || name === "name" || name === "coords" ? ret.value !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
                ret.value :
                undefined;
        },
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            if ( !ret ) {
                elem.setAttributeNode(
                    (ret = elem.ownerDocument.createAttribute( name ))
                );
            }

            ret.value = value += ""; <---- HERE IE 7 CRASHES!!!!!

            // Break association with cloned elements by also using setAttribute (#9646)
            return name === "value" || value === elem.getAttribute( name ) ?
                value :
                undefined;
        }
    };
```

As above indicated, it crashes at following line:

```
ret.value = value += "";
```

ret.value is null and value is "novalidate"

error raise is something like:
javascript runtime error: member not found.

The same error occurs if I execute it from IE 10 and then I switch to compatibility mode.

Could someone tell me how to solve this?

**FIRST ATTEMPT**
I have used the following meta to ensure the latest rendering engine is being used:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Also see below page:
[JQuery Unobtrusive Validation in IE 7 Compatibility Mode causes "Member Not Found" Error in Page with Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013134/jquery-unobtrusive-validation-in-ie-7-compatibility-mode-causes-member-not-foun)

But it seems to not work when using pure IE 7 browser...

any ideas?